# Not caching error signals in Mono.cache()

Tags: project-reactor

Hello good reactor folks - I trying to write some reactive code (surprising eh?) and have hit a slight snag. I think it *might* be a reactor bug, but thought I'd ask here first before posting a bug.

For context: I have a cache `Map<Key, Mono<Value>>`. A client will request data - we check the cache and use what is essentially `computeIfAbsent` to place a `Mono` with `.cache()` into the cache if nothing has yet been cached for that key. The client then takes the `Mono` and *does magic* (not relevant here). Now, the catch is that the population of the cache may encounter transient errors, so we don't want to cache errors - the current request will error but the "next" client, when it subscribes, should trigger the entire pipeline to rerun.

Having read around, for example [this closed issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/391), I settled on [`Mono#cache(ttlForValue, ttlForError, ttlForEmpty)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-).

### This is where things get interesting.

As I don't want to cache `error` (or `empty`, but ignore that) signals I found the following documentation promising

> If the relevant TTL generator throws any `Exception`, that exception will be propagated to the Subscriber that encountered the cache miss, but the **cache will be immediately cleared**, so further Subscribers might re-populate the cache in case the error was transient. In case the source was emitting an error, that error is dropped and added as a suppressed exception. In case the source was emitting a value, that value is dropped.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So I tried the following (shamelessly cribbing the example in the linked GitHub issue)

```java
public class TestBench {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       var sampleService = new SampleService();
       var producer = Mono.fromSupplier(sampleService::call).cache(
               __ -> Duration.ofHours(24),
               //don't cache errors
               e -> {throw Exceptions.propagate(e);},
               //meh
               () -> {throw new RuntimeException();});
       try {
           producer.block();
       } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           System.out.println("Caught exception : " + e);
       }
       sampleService.serverAvailable = true;
       var result = producer.block();
       System.out.println(result);
   }

   static final class SampleService {
       volatile boolean serverAvailable = false;

       String call() {
           System.out.println("Calling service with availability: " + serverAvailable);
           if (!serverAvailable) throw new RuntimeException("Error");
           return "Success";
       }
   }
}
```

Output

```
09:12:23.991 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
Calling service with availability: false
09:12:24.034 [main] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
   at uk.co.borismorris.testbench.TestBench$SampleService.call(TestBench.java:40)
   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:56)
   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribe(MonoCacheTime.java:123)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1474)
   at uk.co.borismorris..boris.testbench.TestBench.main(TestBench.java:26)
Caught exception : reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
   at uk.co.borismorris.testbench.TestBench$SampleService.call(TestBench.java:40)
   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:56)
   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribe(MonoCacheTime.java:123)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1474)
   at uk.co.borismorris.testbench.TestBench.main(TestBench.java:26)
   Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
       at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:93)
       at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1475)
       at uk.co.borismorris.testbench.TestBench.main(TestBench.java:31)
```

Well, that didn't work - the error is cached and the second subscriber just sees the same error.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/8d5748f90fa5bc25fe626e8fece076ea222757e4/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoCacheTime.java#L279) the cause is obvious

```java
Duration ttl = null;
try {
   ttl = main.ttlGenerator.apply(signal);
}
catch (Throwable generatorError) {
   signalToPropagate = Signal.error(generatorError);
   STATE.set(main, signalToPropagate); //HERE
   if (signal.isOnError()) {
       //noinspection ThrowableNotThrown
       Exceptions.addSuppressed(generatorError, signal.getThrowable());
   }
}
```

The `STATE` is set to the `error` signal, not cleared at all. But this isn't the whole story,
 the reason for the code not clearing the cache is below this block

```java
if (ttl != null) {
   main.clock.schedule(main, ttl.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
else {
   //error during TTL generation, signal != updatedSignal, aka dropped
   if (signal.isOnNext()) {
       Operators.onNextDropped(signal.get(), currentContext());
   }
   else if (signal.isOnError()) {
       Operators.onErrorDropped(signal.getThrowable(), currentContext());
   }
   //immediate cache clear
   main.run();
}
```

In this case `ttl == null` because the generation of the `ttl` threw an `Exception`. The `signal` is an `error` so that branch is entered and `Operators.onErrorDropped` is called

```java
public static void onErrorDropped(Throwable e, Context context) {
   Consumer<? super Throwable> hook = context.getOrDefault(Hooks.KEY_ON_ERROR_DROPPED,null);
   if (hook == null) {
       hook = Hooks.onErrorDroppedHook;
   }
   if (hook == null) {
       log.error("Operator called default onErrorDropped", e);
       throw Exceptions.bubble(e);
   }
   hook.accept(e);
}
```

So here we can see that if there is no `onError` hook in the context and no default set then `throw Exceptions.bubble(e)` is called and the code in `MonoCacheTime` returns early, failing to call `main.run()`. Hence the error stays cached *indefinitely* as there is no TTL!

The following code fixes that problem

```java
public class TestBench {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestBench.class);
    private static final Consumer<Throwable> onErrorDropped = e -> logger.error("Dropped", e);

    static {
        //add default hook
        Hooks.onErrorDropped(onErrorDropped);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var sampleService = new SampleService();
        var producer = Mono.fromSupplier(sampleService::call).cache(
                __ -> Duration.ofHours(24),
                //don't cache errors
                e -> {throw Exceptions.propagate(e);},
                //meh
                () -> {throw new RuntimeException();});
        try {
            producer.block();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception : " + e);
        }
        sampleService.serverAvailable = true;
        var result = producer.block();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static final class SampleService {
        volatile boolean serverAvailable = false;

        String call() {
            System.out.println("Calling service with availability: " + serverAvailable);
            if (!serverAvailable) throw new RuntimeException("Error");
            return "Success";
        }
    }

}
```

**But** this adds a global Hook, which isn't ideal. The code hints at the ability to add per-pipeline hooks, but I cannot figure out how to do that. The following works, but is obviously a hack

```java
.subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("reactor.onErrorDropped.local", onErrorDropped))
```

### Questions

1. Is the above a bug, should the absence of a `onErrorDropped` hook cause errors to be cached indefinitely?
2. Is there a way to set the `onErrorDropped` hook in the `subscriberContext` rather than globally?

---

### Follow up

From the code; it seems that returning `null` from a TTL generator function is supported and has the same behaviour when the signal is immediately cleared. In the case where it isn't, the subscriber sees the original error rather than the error from the TTL generator and a suppressed error - which seems perhaps neater

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   var sampleService = new SampleService();
   var producer = Mono.fromSupplier(sampleService::call).cache(
           __ -> Duration.ofHours(24),
           //don't cache errors
           e -> null,
           //meh
           () -> null);
   try {
       producer.block();
   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
       System.out.println("Caught exception : " + e);
   }
   sampleService.serverAvailable = true;
   var result = producer.block();
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

Is this behaviour supported? Should it be documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indeed found a bug! And I think the documentation can also be improved for this variant of `cache`:

1. The focus on how it deals with exceptions inside TTL `Function` is probably misleading
2. There should be a documented straightforward way of "ignoring" a category of signals in the source (which is you case: you want subsequent subscribers to "retry" when the source is erroring).
3. The behavior is bugged due to the use of `onErrorDropped` (which defaults to throwing the dropped exception, thus preventing the `main.run()` state reset).

Unfortunately, the tests use `StepVerifier#verifyThenAssertThat()`, which set an `onErrorDropped` hook, so that last bug was never identified.

Returning `null` in the TTL function is not working better because the same bug happens, but this time with the original source exception being dropped/bubbled.

But there is an ideal semantic for propagating an error to the first subscriber and let the second subscriber retry: **to return `Duration.ZERO` in the ttl `Function`**. This is undocumented, but works right now:

```
IllegalStateException exception = new IllegalStateException("boom");
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Mono<Integer> source = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    int c = count.incrementAndGet();
    if (c == 1) throw exception;
    return c;
});

Mono<Integer> cache = source.cache(v -> Duration.ofSeconds(10),
    e -> Duration.ZERO,
    () -> Duration.ofSeconds(10));

assertThat(cache.retry().block()).isEqualTo(2);
```

I'll open an issue to fix the state reset bug and focus the javadoc on the above solution, while moving the bit dealing with throwing TTL Functions in a separate shorter paragraph at the end.

edit: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1783

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! `Duration.ZERO` would schedule the clearing task to happen immediately rather than directly invoking `run`, correct? Are there cases where this would result in a different outcome - for example in the case of many simultaneous subscribers?

Comment: In terms of the per-`SubscriberContext` hooks; is there any documentation of that? I couldn't find a way to set one - perhaps it's just for internal use?

Comment: the per-subscriberContext hooks for onErrorDropped are indeed undocumented and unofficial.`Duration.ZERO` would typically translate to `ExecutorService#submit`, so there can be a slight delay. Many simultaneous subscribers is tricky, they will either gather under the same coordinator SUBSCRIBERS array and receive the same signal or come in just after the state reset in which case they'll get added to their own new coordinator (with a new source subscription), so I don't think specifically translating ZERO to `clearingTask.run()` is needed